# Is "How would you like your coffee?" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

I know this is something small but I am genuinely curious about it.  Are questions like "How would you like your coffee?" grammatically correct? Isn't it supposed to be "How would you like your coffee to be?"? Are both of these correct? Could you explain the reason and the rule behind it, please? Thank you so much.

Comment: Adding an unnecessary *to be* at the end is sometimes a useful thought experiment for finding the correct pronoun case; but adding it on here would likely just confuse a native speaker.

Comment: I think a more common way of asking is "How do you take your coffee?" (That version, though, implies that established habit must always prevail.)

Comment: Perfectly idiomatic, at least in the UK. General reference: << **how do [/would] you like...?**
 
used when asking someone how they [would] like their drinks [/fried eggs etc] made [/cooked]:
_"How do you like your tea?" "Milk and one sugar, please."_ >> [[Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/how-do-you-like)]

Comment: The question is not really about the grammatical correctness (there isn't anything that would even appear to be a grammatical error in it), but about what leads us to interpret *how* in it as concerning the mode of preparing the coffee, rather that the mode of liking it, which would be indicated by the syntax of the sentence, considered in the abstract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is grammatically correct, though it is a shortening of "How would you like your coffee *prepared*?" or "How would you like *me to make* your coffee?" or the example you provided. They are all correct, but the one you wrote sounds a bit less natural, in my opinion.

Due to the context of the situation, the *prepared* part is implied and often omitted by the speaker for the sake of brevity. The listener knows that the other person intends to make the coffee.

It is similar to "What type of coffee do you want?" Again, the *prepared* part is implied and is unnecessary. A native speaker would understand, whichever version you decide to use.

Comment: Thank you so much for your clear and quick answer.

Comment: May I ask is this in passive voice?

Comment: @Guri These examples are all in active voice. Using passive voice in a question like this would be very odd: "What type of coffee is liked by you?" Anyway, I'm glad I could help!

Comment: Thank you. Then is it correct to ask 'How would you like your dog'? or is it 'how would you like your dog to be.'

Comment: @Guri Not necessarily. The coffee example works because there are many specific ways to prepare coffee, and the phrase is commonly used in that context. In this dog situation, there would not be a specific way for someone to answer the question, and a native speaker would be very confused by both ways of you asking the question. The "how would you like your..." phrase is used almost exclusively for inanimate objects like coffee, food, or flowers, and it is typically used by someone who wishes to make or prepare the object.

Comment: @harade I got it now! Thank you so much for your time, effort and making my doubts clear.

Comment: @Guri No problem! By clicking the little checkmark next to my answer, you can accept it, which will show others that is the best solution.

Comment: Not sure why it got down voted, it is a perfectly fine answer. I +1ed to correct. FWIW, I think it should be a requirement to add a comment explaining your downvote.